# Where can I find an official set of iOS (specifically iPad) icons and stencil sets?

Tags: gui-design, icons, ios, ipad, apple

Android have an official set of icons, fonts, colours and stencils, that can be downloaded from their website.

However, I have come to design for iPad and I can't find an official download. Do I need to create icons manually!! I don't have time for that. :). No, the main reason I want to find an official downloadable set of icons is to maintain consistency across my app and for familiarity. **Does an official iOS icon set exist?** Preferably raster and vectors.

I have found a thrid party GUI psd (see link below) that contains some icons but I need a more comprehensive set:
http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/ipad-gui-psd-retina-display/

**Do I have to settle for my own custom icons and third party icon sets?**

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Exchange as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Apple developer library, human interface guidelines? There is an excellent reference on creating custom icons, along with descriptions of the standard icons, fonts, widgets and controls and their appropriate usage.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

If you are looking for prototyping stencils, there are some excellent ones on the [Axure community site](http://www.axure.com/download-widget-libraries).

Comment: Thanks, I've already read that riveting document front to back. I understand the spec for the icons but id rather not create my own, I want a prebuilt official set to use.

Comment: Do you have a link to "Axure community site" where these exist?

Comment: I'm traveling, so forgive any typos:http://www.axure.com/download-widget-libraries

Comment: Added link to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**[This project on Github](https://github.com/davidmorford/iOSDesignStencils)** has a pretty comprehensive, community-driven set of icons for the iPad. Below is a preview of this GUI Stencil Set. It seems to be standards-driven, and not arbitrarily sized/styled.

[image]

Similarly, **[here is another set of iPad elements](http://iconlibrary.iconshock.com/icons/ipad-vector-gui-elements-tabs-buttons-menus-icons/)**, this time in .AI and with a few different elements. The preview image is way too large to link here, but [**here's the URL to a preview**](http://iconlibrary.iconshock.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/ipad-vector-buttons-GUI.jpg).

If it's specifically the icons you need to make, [**this free .PSD**](http://medialoot.com/item/iphone-app-icon-kit/) uses smart objects to automatically make your button from a flat image.

Comment: Thanks. The first link contains .gstencil files, I can't open these, I need Adobe Photoshop/Illustrator compatible file formats. The second link is more useful, there's a couple of icons on there I can use but still not a comprehensive collection.

Answer (score 0):

Kintek provides a comprehensive set of resources for anyone designing on iOS and Android. As far as I know, there is no official set of icons that Apple publicizes, but they do have excellent guidelines on what to do and what not to do when creating new icons on their interfaces.

http://kintek.com.au/blog/portkit-ux-metaphor-equivalents-for-ios-and-android/

Comment: Awesome link! love the comparisons between ios7, ios6 and android. The links they provide are also useful but I still can't find a set of icons that I can download and use in my designs. As you say, "As far as I know, there is no official set of icons that Apple publicizes", maybe it jsut doesnt exist. Maybe i'll have to create my own! :(

Answer (score 0):

I've found a free set of icons here but its still not comprehensive - http://www.glyphish.com/ - direct download link: http://glyphish.com/download/glyphish-icons.zip

I've also discovered there is an Apple Symbols font which contains alot of the Appley glyphs - its talked about here http://oleb.net/blog/2009/10/apple-symbols-font-repository-for-iphone-icons/. However i'm working in Windows so I don't have access to this font.

Comment: He was looking for official ones, I guess so he stays on the right side of apple